# Second VHOST not accepting $_SESSION variable

Tags: php, apache, session

I have an apache config with 2 vhosts.  Both are the same aside from different IP's and DNS entries.

I have php code which does the following.

`session_start();`

Later, I check for a session variable.

`if (isset($_SESSION["clist"])) {`

If it's NOT set, in the `} else {`, I read from the database, then write the results.

`$_SESSION['clist'] = $records;`

clist is a list of the countries and their country-codes, which I use to populate a dropdown.

When the dropdown is changed, I post the form to a handler page, then come back to the original page.

On the first VHOST, this works as intended.  When I move the code to the second VHOST, the conditional tests false, so I go through the same process of pulling data from the database.

I did a little debug test with:

`var_dump($_SESSION);`

When I look at the dump, the first thing I see at the top is:

```
array(1) {
  ["clist"]=>
```

Is there something else that may be causing this issue?

Comment: what does this have to do with php ?  configs ,maybe, apache configs, maybe. But php code ?

Comment: Since I don't know what the problem is, it may be something I am overlooking in PHP.  Is that not the point of a question?  I flagged everything I am using to allow people to know the environments I am in.